# Monitoring Bigquery views usage

Tags: view, google-bigquery, monitoring, looker-studio

I'm a data engineer and I have to manage a GCP project with mostly views into the differents datasets, as we use this project only to transform data from our lakehouse (another GCP project) to PowerBI. Only expensive or low queries are materialized as tables. Therefore we are able to monitor usage through our differents projects for the tables (bq tables and external tables like biglake tables), but I can't see the usage of the views into my dashboard. As we create and manage a lot of views for different stakeholders, we want to make sure they are used and if not, we want to delete them. Estimate the cost of a view would be also really appreciate but not the fist priority, as the cost in bigquery are calculated based the amount of the data read into the source table. Is there a way to monitor this ? Like the job count per day of views queried in bigquery ?